# Can members of the Electoral College also cast a "normal" vote?

Tags: united-states, presidential-election, electoral-college

Are members of the Electoral College allowed to vote in the general election?

It would make perfect sense that they could cast a ballot like everyone else (because there's stuff on the ballot besides president), but are they allowed to vote for president?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, of course electors can vote in the general election and for president. Elected officials are permitted to cast ballots in favor of themselves and similarly an elector can vote for their intended candidate and themselves.

Comment: Besides which, at the time of the election, they are only *potential* Electors;   the other party has a set as well.   Choosing a set of Electors from several sets  is what the whole Presidential election is about.

Comment: Actually @DJohnM, according to the Minutes of the Constitutional Convention and Alexander Hamilton's writings as *Publius*, our Founding Fathers never planned for electors to be chosen in "sets" or to have an "intended" candidate. Per Federalist Paper 68 they meant for them to be selected individually by their local peers on election day and then to gather in each state on the same day and *deliberate* on the matter. What we have today, a pre-set group hand-picked by the party elite to rubber-stamp the party's choice, is quite different than what the writers of the Constitution wanted.